# Jquery datepicker positioning problem: date picker blocks half of a text field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is a HTML markup

```
<tr><td><b>Effective Date</b></td><td colspan="2"><input class="datepicker " value="01/04/2011" ></td></tr>
```

(Unfortunately I have little control over the markup. So 'an INPUT in a TD in a TR' is a given)

In the javascript I do the standard

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

And it is the outcome

[image]

The datepicker somehow blocks half of the INPUT box.

Why it is the case? And what is a possible solution?

Same result in Chrome and FF4

Comment: I've used date pickers inside table cells without any problem whatsoever. Did you tweak the UI's CSS?

Comment: use firebug and see the css for both datepicker and input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), inspect the elements, figure out why exactly is it showing the way it is (hint: it's because of CSS `:)`. Then use jQuery's `.css` function to change the CSS.

You can use multiple rules at once, like this:

```
$(".datepicker").css({
    "margin-top": "10px",
    "width": "auto"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

set the inline style for input something like

```
<input class="datepicker " value="01/04/2011" style "position:relative;top:10px;" >
```

**note:** Better see in firebug and adjust the class, this is just minor style issue..